# How to use Two forms in Django Templates, And how to call different function when it submit the form

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using two forms in one template. When i submit the 2nd form its calling first form only i'm little bit confusing where i did mistake anyone help me in this.

index.html

```
<form action="#" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<a href="{% url 'app:profile' %}"><button type="submit"> Submit</button></a>
</form>

<form action="#" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="review" id="review">
<a href="{% url 'app:feedback' %}"><button type="submit"> Submit</button></a>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Some operation
        return render(request, 'index.html', {})

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        res = User(username=username)
        res.save()
        return redirect('/home/')
    return redirect('/login/')

def feedback(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        review= request.POST.get('review')
        res = Feedback(comment=review)
        res.save()
        return redirect('/home/')
    return redirect('/home/')
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
   path('profile/', views.profile, name="profile"),
   path('feedback/', views.feedback, name="feedback"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the actions should be different to identify which form will make post request to which view:

```
<form action="{% url 'app:profile' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>

<form action="{% url 'app:feedback' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="review" id="review">
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute in submit.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<a href="{% url 'app:profile' %}"><button type="submit" name="attr_name"> Submit</button></a>
</form>
```

And check the name in views.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'attr_name' in request.POST:
        # Some operation
```

Comment: First form is working fine. What i do for second form it's not calling feedback function when i click second form submit button.

Comment: feedback function will not be called because you have not called template in it. And also you should not use index.html for both views. If you want both forms in one template merge the views. and it will work